# SharePoint 2013 Calendar - hide the ability to add event

Tags: calendar

I have a SharePoint calendar. I have web parts on other pages wich uses code to write events to my calendar. I don't want the user to be able to add events to the calendar directly - only the web parts should write events. How can I disable the +Add link on the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the page in `Edit mode`, locate the `Edit Web Part` drop down on either the Calendar or the list for the calendar (depending on the view), and while the web part is in edit mode under the `List Views` section change the `Toolbar Type` to `No Toolbar`. I've had to do this on numerous lists where I have either a solution that adds items to a list, or an InfoPath form library.  Hope this helps!