# Remove "+Add" from Calendar View Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a Calendar View web part that I've placed in a SharePoint page. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I want to prevent the user from editing the list from here--I have an app that will take care of editing.
To accomplish this I want to hide/remove the "+Add" button.

Any idea how to hide/remove it?

---

I see [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82573/sharepoint-2013-calendar-hide-the-ability-to-add-event) question seems similar, but when I tried that solution I still see the "+Add" button. Perhaps I did something wrong? Or do I continue to see the buttons because I have elevated permissions on the SharePoint site?

Comment: I think the other answer refers to +Add buttons at the top or bottom of list views, not within a calendar.

Answer (score 9):

Just hiding/removing `+Add` button, does not prevent the user from creating calendar Events using Calendar View, since the Events could be created by clicking inside calendar area.

So, if you are interested not only in hiding/removing `+Add` button you could consider the following approach.

### How to disable the calendar events

Example 1

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

   //Disable calendar events
   $('.ms-acal-rootdiv td').on("mousedown mouseup dblclick mousemove", false);

}, 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js');
```

Example 2

```
$("body").on("mousedown mouseup dblclick mousemove", ".ms-acal-rootdiv td", false);
```

Usage

- Add Content Editor on Calendar page
- Insert the provided JavaScript code:

Comment: I see what this is trying to do--use JavaScript to modify what the default click event does, and hide the add button. It seems like the right solution for me. Unfortunately, when I placed it in a Content Editor or Script Editor on the page with the calendar nothing seems to happen. "+Add" is still displayed and I can still click to add events.

Comment: I'll verify it some later today and get back to you

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: The answer has been updated and it works for me

Comment: Ok, for some reason it still doesn't seem to have any effect. I wrapped the provided code in `<script>` tags and tried placing it inside of a content editor (and script editor). The calendar on the page appears to behave normally.

Comment: I forgot to mention, it requires jQuery library 1.7 or later

Comment: I did this `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

   //Disable calendar events
   $('.ms-acal-rootdiv td').on("mousedown mouseup dblclick mousemove", false);
}, 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js');
</script>` at the top of the page with my calendar web part inside a script editor. No change.

Comment: Hi, please try the example 2 from the updated answer

Comment: It should look like this then? `<script> $("body").on("mousedown mouseup dblclick mousemove", ".ms-acal-rootdiv td", false);
</script>` If so, there's still probably an issue with how I'm doing this, although it seems just like your example... (The way I have it written doesn't work for me.)

Comment: Hmm, you are correctly embedding JS code, but have yet no idea why it does not work for you..

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of a configuration setting that will turn off the Add button in the Calendar but you can hide it by placing a Content Editor web part on the page and adding the following CSS to the Content Editor. Be sure to click the Edit Source button in the ribbon and paste it in the HTML Source.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-acal-rootdiv A[title="Add"]{ display:none; }
</style>
```

Comment: This technique does successfully hide the "+Add" button, but Vadim Gremyachev is correct in saying that it won't actually prevent people from adding events by clicking on that day on the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyCalendarHook, 'SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js');
function MyCalendarHook() {                     
    var calendarCreate = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create;
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create = function (elem, cctx, viewType, date, startupData) {
        cctx.canUserCreateItem = false;
        calendarCreate(elem, cctx, viewType, date, startupData);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way can be set user permisions to this calendar, to "View items" only, then add button will disapear for users